# angular filter pipe on multiple values of table columns

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I'm trying to implement filter pipe on multiple value on multiple attribute in a table.

I'm able to filter multiple value on one attribute. But I'm not able to do it for  multiple values of multiple attributes.

My pipe filter implementation for multiple value in a single attribute,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'vFilter',
  pure: false
})

export class VFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(vList: any[], vfilter?: any): any {
    if (!vList|| !Object.keys(vfilter).length) {
      return vList;
    } 
    return vList.filter(item => {
          for (let key in vfilter) {
            for(let value in vfilter[key]){
             if ((item[key] === undefined || item[key] == vfilter[key][value])) 
             {
              return true;
             }
           }
           return false;
         }
         return false;
       });
  }
}
```

My input array is given ,

```
vList = [{'name':'jack','age':'25'},{'name':'sam','age':'25'},{'name':'smith','age':'25'},{'name':'jack','age':'28'}]

vfilter = {'name':['jack','sam'],'age':['25']}
```

I expect the output like the one below after filtering,

```
vList = [{'name':'jack','age':'25'},{'name':'sam','age':'25'}]
```

But I'm getting the below result,

```
vList = [{'name':'jack','age':'25'},{'name':'sam','age':'25'},{'name':'jack','age':'28'}]
```

can anyone help me on solving this logical problem.

Comment: not an answer to your logic issue, but this is a poor use for a pipe.  Impure pipes are very inefficient and can be performance drags.  You'd be better off setting up this filter logic in your controller and running it when it needs to be updated rather than relying on change detection

Comment: Thank you @bryan60 for the suggestion. I have changed my implementation from pipe to component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logic bug is that you are returning `true` if any of the filters match when you want to only return true if all the filters match.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-18dkev)

```
transform(vList: any[], vfilter?: any): any {
  if (!vList || !Object.keys(vfilter).length) {
    return vList;
  } 
  return vList.filter(item => {
          return Object.keys(vfilter)
            .filter(_ => vfilter.hasOwnProperty(_))
            .every(key => {
              if(!item[key]) return true; // matches undefined value
              const arrayValues = vfilter[key] as any[];
              return arrayValues.some(_ => _ === item[key]);
          });
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Igor for the solution. It's working for me.